# $A.createComponent fails with internal server on create aura:HTML with body

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, dynamiccomponent

The following code fails:

```
$A.createComponent(
        "aura:HTML",
         { tag: "div",
         body: 'value',
         HTMLAttributes:{"id": "Temp","class": "class name here"}
         },
        function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
            var container = component.find('root');
            if (container.isValid() && newCmp!= null) {
                var body = container.get("v.body");
                body.push(newCmp);
                container.set("v.body", body);
            }
        }
    );
```

Error:

```
 render threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' [Assertion Failed!: Descriptor for Config required for registration : undefined] Failing descriptor: {markup://aura:html}
```

And the same code without "body: 'value'" creates div block:

```
$A.createComponent(
        "aura:HTML",
         { tag: "div",
         HTMLAttributes:{"id": "Temp","class": "class name here"}
         },
        function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
            var container = component.find('root');
            if (container.isValid() && newCmp!= null) {
                var body = container.get("v.body");
                body.push(newCmp);
                container.set("v.body", body);
            }
        }
    );
```

Also I tried to set body after component was created:

```
newCmp.set("v.body", 'value');
```

Also got error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `aura:html` instead of `aura:HTML` . Always remember everything in lightning is case-sensitive.

Here's the sample code which I tried in my org.

**myApp.app:**

```
<aura:application access="global">
    <div aura:id="root"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="{!c.createDivCmp}">Creat Div</button>
</aura:application>
```

**myAppController.js**

```
({
    createDivCmp : function(component,event,helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "aura:html",
            { tag: "div",
                body: 'value',
                HTMLAttributes:{"id": "Temp","class": "class name here"}
            },
            function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
                var container = component.find('root');
                if (component.isValid() && container.isValid() && status === 'SUCCESS') {
                    var body = container.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newCmp);
                    container.set("v.body", body);
                }
            }
        );
    }
})
```